# Android classes called twice

Tags: java, android

I am experiencing strange log cat behaviour in my app, either I have two activities running at the same time, or log cat is duplicating all my logs.

Here is the stack trace from when my app starts:

> 01-03 08:27:38.020: I/Start(25855): App starting
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.020: I/Start(25855): App starting
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.030: I/Start(25855): API key found - starting MainActivity
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.030: I/Start(25855): API key found - starting MainActivity
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.050: D/ActivityThread(25855): <<< done: 100
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.050: E/ActivityThread(25855): >>> handling: 101
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.070: D/ActivityThread(25855): <<< done: 101
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.070: E/ActivityThread(25855): >>> handling: 100
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.180: D/dalvikvm(25855): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 59K, 49% free 2787K/5379K,
> external 1625K/2137K, paused 84ms
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.290: V/MainActivity(25855): Main activity starting
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.290: V/MainActivity(25855): Main activity starting
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.320: I/class com.visualdenim.schooltraq.MainActivity(25855): Adapter is open
>
> 01-03 08:27:38.320: I/class com.visualdenim.schooltraq.MainActivity(25855): Adapter is open

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in my handset, as when I try developing with a different phone, I don't get this anomaly.

Comment: what handset and what version of android were you using? im experiencing the same problem, im using a zte blade (aka orange san francisco) with android 2.3.5 (gingerbread)

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from a bug in logcat that sometimes duplicates the lines. Restart adb and/or logcat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have reset ADB to no effect. How do you reset logcat?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse, or unplugging and plugging the device again?